# jquery tabbed selector with dropdown selectors, dropdowns don't match on tab switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Thanks to help from members oka and Mike Robinson, I have managed to build two tables that users will view and play with using tabs and dropdowns.

My two tables have identical structures, each has an identical drop-down menu to show/hide columns. The idea is for the user to select a "choice" from the drop down, then tab over to the other table and compare choices.

Everything works, EXCEPT -- when you tab over to the other table, the correct column -- '.target' -- is shown (and the correct columns -- '.choice' -- are hidden) but the drop down resets to its default. So the drop down displays one choice; the shown columns display another, which will confuse viewers.

The code "remembers" which choices were hidden and which target was shown, but the drop down doesn't.

I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas what's going on?

Here are the jquery, css, html, and snippet:

```js
    
       function keepSelect() { 
             var val = $(this).val();
             var target = '.' + val;
             $('.choice').hide();
             $(target).show();
       }
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.sel').on('change', keepSelect).change();
         $(document).on('change', '.sel', keepSelect).change();

                   $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
           var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
           $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
           $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
           $(this).addClass('current');
           $('#' + tab_id).addClass('current');
         })
       })
```

```css
 body {
   margin-top: 1px;
   font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
   line-height: 1.6
 }
 .container {
   position: absolute;
   width: 25%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 ul.tabs {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;
 }
 ul.tabs li {
   background: none;
   color: #222;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid red;
   width: 25%;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 8pt;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: normal;
 }
 ul.tabs li.current {
   background: #ededed;
   color: #222;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 10pt;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .tab-content {
   display: none;
   background: none;
   padding: 15px;
 }
 .tab-content.current {
   display: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li class='tab-link current' data-tab='tab-1'>ViewA</li>
    <li class='tab-link' data-tab='tab-2'>ViewB</li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab-1' class='tab-content current'>
    <select class="sel">
      <option class="one" value="one">1</option>
      <option class="two" value="two">2</option>
    </select>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th class="choice one">Choice One</th>
        <th class="choice two">Choice Two</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type1</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td class="choice one">100</td>
        <td class="choice two">200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type2</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td class="choice one">40</td>
        <td class="choice two">90</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='tab-2' class='tab-content'>
    <select class="sel">
      <option class="one" value="one">1</option>
      <option class="two" value="two">2</option>
    </select>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th class="choice one">Choice One</th>
        <th class="choice two">Choice Two</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type1</td>
        <td>55.56</td>
        <td class="choice one">2.9</td>
        <td class="choice two">9.87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type2</td>
        <td>350</td>
        <td class="choice one">4.05</td>
        <td class="choice two">8.77</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the only problem is that the wrong value is being selected in the dropdown when you go to another tab right? You just need to set the attribute "selected" on the option you want selected

Comment: the problem is, after you select 2 from the dropdown (and it correctly hides the column corresponding to 1) and then click on ViewB, the ViewB table's dropdown has been reset back to 1 (while showing the 2 column).

Comment: I suggest refactoring the jQuery code more first, taking out unnecessary lines to reduce clutter, such as using ".click()" instead of ".on("click"". Also, the html "id" is unique, but you have two ids of "sel"

Comment: I should have mentioned -- there are more columns -- choices -- in the actual tables. Setting the "selected" attribute might be the way to go, but how do I set it to the most recently dropped down option? I want the dropdown in the clicked-to table to remember both the hidden/shown columns from the previous View, AND display the corresponding drop down. That way viewers can with a single click compare the clicked-to table with the clicked-from table.

Comment: Jean-Paul -- yes, there are two identical "id"s. I tried to deal with that by changing "sel" to a class, but got the exact same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.choice').hide();
    $('.one').show();

    $('.sel').change(function(){
        $('.choice').hide();
        $( '.' + this.value).show();
        $('.sel').val( this.value );
    });

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#' + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkq4277/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sel').change(function(){
        $('.choice').hide();
        $( '.'+this.value).show();
        $('.sel').val( this.value );
    });
    
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#' + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

```css
 body {
     margin-top: 1px;
     font-family:'Trebuchet MS', serif;
     line-height: 1.6
 }
 .container {
     position: absolute;
     width: 25%;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
 ul.tabs {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     list-style: none;
 }
 ul.tabs li {
     background: none;
     color: #222;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 3px solid red;
     width: 25%;
     font-family: Verdana;
     font-size: 8pt;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: normal;
 }
 ul.tabs li.current {
     background: #ededed;
     color: #222;
     font-family: Verdana;
     font-size: 10pt;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 .tab-content {
     display: none;
     background: none;
     padding: 15px;
 }
 .tab-content.current {
     display: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    <ul class='tabs'>
        <li class='tab-link current' data-tab='tab-1'>ViewA</li>
        <li class='tab-link' data-tab='tab-2'>ViewB</li>
    </ul>
    <div id='tab-1' class='tab-content current'>
        <select class="sel">
            <option class="one" value="one">1</option>
            <option class="two" value="two">2</option>
        </select>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th class="choice one">Choice One</th>
                <th class="choice two">Choice Two</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>type1</td>
                <td>5000</td>
                <td class="choice one">100</td>
                <td class="choice two">200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>type2</td>
                <td>350</td>
                <td class="choice one">40</td>
                <td class="choice two">90</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id='tab-2' class='tab-content'>
        <select class="sel">
            <option class="one" value="one">1</option>
            <option class="two" value="two">2</option>
        </select>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th class="choice one">Choice One</th>
                <th class="choice two">Choice Two</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>type1</td>
                <td>55.56</td>
                <td class="choice one">2.9</td>
                <td class="choice two">9.87</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>type2</td>
                <td>350</td>
                <td class="choice one">4.05</td>
                <td class="choice two">8.77</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's great, thanks very much @gibberish -- what a relief! This does the important thing: matches option values with the shown "choice" columns. Any thoughts on how I can get it to hide the "choice 2" column when the table first loads (instead of displaying both of the "choice" columns)?

Comment: See updated answer -- added two lines at top that should do the trick.

Comment: awesome -- that solved it! I hadn't even thought of setting "one." You have saved me days of tinkering and staring (possibly even swearing) at my computer screen. thanks very much!